# Implement security for sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a share-point list with which I want to implement three things:

1. Freeze some columns so that their data can be edited by specific people only like the ones within **site owners** group with full privileges.
2. Hide some columns according to some user groups. Earlier I did this by creating **two views**, one with limited columns selected and visible to all and one with all columns with filter `Restricted_user = [Me]` and I have put all users' names from active directory in that field, but I guess it has security loopholes like someone could see all row data by selecting **view item** and everything in that row will be visible to him.

   2.1. If my own second option approach is selected can I implement this comparison with **group aliases**, rather than individuals so that I have to put only group aliases in that column field, rather that all names in that group aliases.
3. Last but not the least can i break up list rows into two categories so that two different groups can access and edit their own data only.Eg. 20 rows are there 5 accessible to group1  and 15 accessible to group2 but they cant access each others data rows.

Apologies for long question.

Comment: IS My QUESTION CLEAR ENOUGH???  OR NEEDS TO ADD MORE DETAILS!!

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way to accomplish #3 is using [item level permissions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2007/07/04/how-to-set-item-level-permission-for-moss-wss-list-document-library-programmatically.aspx). Less secure ways include custom views and audiences.

For #1 and #2, you will need to create [custom field types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Out of the box SharePoint list columns do not support column based security.